# How to match space or \s via regex in awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to match the following pattern and ended up \s not being matched. Not sure what am I missing.

This is the sample file.

```
There was a farmer, who had a dog
and Bingo : nameo
Bingo: nameio
```

and I am using following to match the string after "Bingo\s*:\s*"

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/Bingo[ : ]*/) print $(i+1)}' sample.log
```

Expecting the string "nameo" after the first match but I get ":"  and second match is just fine and I get "nameio".

Can someone please help me explain why space is not being matched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[ : ]` (in your regex) is a character class matching a single space or colon. Awk fields are split on white space by default, so `Bingo :`  is is two fields, not one. By default, a field will never contain white space.

I would probably add `:` to the default field separator regex:

```
awk -v FS='[[:space:]:]+' '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i == "Bingo") {
            print $(i+1)
        }
    }
}'
```

Although that does split strings like `foo:bar` in to two fields. If that's problematic, maybe something like this:

```
awk '
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i == "Bingo" && $(i+1) = ":") {
            print $(i+2)
        }
    }
}'
```

In answer to your title, `\s` is not valid awk. Apart from a raw space ( ), there is:

- `[[:space:]]` matches any white space character (space, tab, new line, carriage return, form feed, vertical tabs)
- `[[:blank:]]` matches space or tab

Comment: Glad it helped. One other thing I though of would be to check that `i+1` (or `i+2`) is not greater than `NF`, to avoid printing an empty line in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I would do that too! Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

The `[ : ]*` pattern part is equal to `[: ]*` and represents a *bracket expression* that matches zero or more (as many as possible, due to `*`) colons or literal spaces. In your case, the spaces  are used as field separators and thus are not part of the field values, so you can't use your logic with the default field separator.

There are a lot of ways to solve the problem, here are three:

```
awk 'match($0,/Bingo : .*/){print substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH)}' file
sed -n 's/^.*Bingo : \(.*\)/\1/p' file
grep -oP 'Bingo : \K.+' file
```

The `awk 'match($0,/Bingo : .*/){print substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH)}' file` command uses `awk` to find a record (line) with `Bingo :`  and any text after, matching this substring, and returning a substring beginning with match start position + 8 (the length of `Bingo :`  text).

The `sed -n 's/^.*Bingo : \(.*\)/\1/p'` command suppresses default line output with `-n`  option, then finds a line with `Bingo :` , captures any text after this substring into Group 1, replaces the whole line with this value and only prints this result of substitution.

The GNU `grep` `grep -oP 'Bingo : \K.+'` command matches (with the PCRE regex engine, see `-P` option) and outputs (using `-o` option) one or more chars after `Bingo :`  text (`\K` makes the regex engine "forget" the text matched so far).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/QZDVNW):

```
#!/bin/bash
s='There was a farmer, who had a dog
and Bingo : nameo
Bingo: nameio'
awk 'match($0,/Bingo : .*/){print substr($0,RSTART+8,RLENGTH)}' <<< "$s"
sed -n 's/^.*Bingo : \(.*\)/\1/p' <<< "$s"
grep -oP 'Bingo : \K.+' <<< "$s"
```

Output is `nameo` after each command.